# Decoding I-Frame H264 bytes to JPEG format

Tags: ffmpeg, byte, h.264, decoder

I have an **array of bytes** that represents **an I-Frame** from h264 camera stream.

How can I convert these bytes to jpeg or other picture format. With or without using decoders?

**Notice:**
I know ffmpeg can decode I-Frame from video, but my problem is that my input data is not video, as I said its a series of bytes from camera stream with known buffer size length.

Comment: You can "decode" from one format to another. you must decode to a raw image, the encode to the desired format.

Comment: What programing language? If it has **standard input/output** (eg: `stdio` or `stdin`), then you could start FFmpeg as external **process** and feed it the bytes by using `-` as input (`-i`) source. Example : `ffmpeg -i - output.jpg`

Comment: Did you make any progress ?